# Make elements inside div ignore it's container size and make the container scrollable instead

Tags: html

I have a problem with my div elements.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
<!-- Some stuff here -->
</div>
```

How can I make the elements inside it not go to next line and make the div horizontally scrollable instead?

Comment: overflow-x: scroll for horizontal scrolling. To make contents inside not drop to next line make them display: inline or display:inline-block

Comment: Use this `overflow-x: scroll;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use overflow-x

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <img width="400" height = "300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: they said horizontally scroll, not vertically scroll. overflow-y is vertical. overflow-x is horizontal

Comment: I haven't noticed